# Fixed div (menu to the left) does not fill 100% when scrolling is possible

Tags: html, css

I could use some help solving this css problem. Basically, I have 3 sections.

```
div class="app-container">
    <div class="menu">
    </div>
    <div class="content">
    </div>
</div
```

The menu div, should contain my menu. It should be displayed on the left side with a fixed width. The height should also be 100%.

The content div, should use what's rest of the width available.

This is how my site looks like now.

[image]

The problem happens when there it more content to the right, and you have to scroll down to view it. When this happens, my menu does not follow along.

This is how it looks when there are way more content. (you can see to the right that I have scrolled down)

[image]

**Code**

```
html, body {

}

.app-container {

}

.menu {
  height: 100%;
  width: 16rem;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #2D3E50;
  color: white;
  padding: 1rem;
  position: absolute;
}

.content {
  padding: 1rem;
  padding-left: 17rem;
  background-color: white;
  height: 100%;
}
```

As you can see, I have made a padding-left on the content, and filled in the menu in the absolute position.

What should I do so the menu keeps continuing no matter how far you scroll down?

**Update**

[image]

Comment: Try using position relative to body and position absolute to your menu element. Set height to 100%.

Comment: yes this works, I would write this up as the answer

Answer (score 0):

Try using `position: relative;` to `body` and `position: absolute;` to your menu element. Set height of the menu to 100%.

Comment: If I do that, it works when there are more content than the window can show (when you can scroll), but if there only are 2 lines of "Content here", the menu will only fill out the that.

Comment: What do you mean by `the menu will only fill out the that`?

Comment: @Mikkel set `html, body {height: 100%;}`